# Warning when training a custom model using tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, transfer-learning

I have been using below tensorflow object detection tutorial to build a custom object detector.

https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I have run according to the instructions provided in the google colab with GPU support and then in AWS EC2 instance with GPU support. In both of the cases,I am getting warning and model training stops there.

I have used EfficientDet D6 model from tensorflow 2 detection model garden.

Below is the warning which stops the model training.

*WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.axis
W0910 14:45:44.534728 140520822372160 util.py:203] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.gamma
W0910 14:45:44.534780 140520822372160 util.py:203] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.beta
W0910 14:45:44.534832 140520822372160 util.py:203] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.moving_mean
W0910 14:45:44.534884 140520822372160 util.py:203] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.moving_variance
W0910 14:45:44.534937 140520822372160 util.py:203] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._bifpn_stage.node_input_blocks.7.0.1.1.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
W0910 14:45:44.534990 140520822372160 util.py:211] A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights*

Any help or pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `expect_partial()` on the load status object,
e.g. `tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial()`, to silence these warnings,
or use `assert_consumed()`.
[Official Document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Deep. However,it seems that expect_partial is useful to load a saved model. model = tf.keras.Model(...)
tf.saved_model.save(model, path)  # or model.save(path, save_format='tf')

checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model)
checkpoint.restore(path).expect_partial().  These are from official guides

Comment: I have tried to run SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320,and got the below errors.   ValueError: Cannot assign to variable WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor/WeightSharedConvolutionalClassHead/ClassPredictor/bias:0 due to variable shape (66,) and value shape (18,) are incompatible
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).save_counter

Comment: After this error,program pointed below warnings and stopped unfortunately.  W0916 07:32:58.886545 140440812377920 util.py:203] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).save_counter
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit.

Comment: W0916 07:32:58.886786 140440812377920 util.py:211] A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.